# Unable to override ListProduct block in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to override product list page but changes are not getting reflected in front end as it still referring to the core block.

Following is the code,

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" 
            type="TestApp\Blog\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

ListProduct.php

```
<?php
namespace TestApp\Blog\Block\Rewrite\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct{
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So this means your override is not working. Or some other module may have override same file. So enable path hint with show block name and check which block class is loading

Comment: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor

This block is being shown.

Comment: have you tried after command `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` also checke is there any module who has override same file?

Comment: You code seems fine, clear cache and check if you module is enable.

Comment: And if you have production mode enabled then run compile command

Comment: @KumarM you have to override this(getLoadedProductCollection()) function also

Comment: Once file get overrided you can do rewrite any function. And if you want to modify results of this function then don't use preference use plugin to use afterGetLoadedProductCollection

Answer (score 1):

You need to add di.xml file into the `etc/frontend/di.xml` file

make sure you flush the cache, di compile if you already did

I hope It's help for you